# Solving a nonlinear (vector or multi-variable) ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am interested in solving the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}=A\mathbf{w}, \qquad \mathbf{v}=\left[x,y\right]^T, \mathbf{w}=[x^2,y^2,xy]^T, A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 3}$$

Equivalently, for $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}, \quad\forall i,j$
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = a_{11}x^2+a_{12}y^2+a_{13}xy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = a_{21}x^2+a_{22}y^2+a_{23}xy$$

I have noticed that
$$\mathbf{vv^T}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}x^2&xy\\xy&y^2\end{array}\right]$$

I'm looking for analytical solution to this problem.

Comment: Many people in interested in solving that equation. What is your question?

Comment: @JohnB I'm looking for a closed form solution to this equation. The context of the problem is that I am trying to discretize system dynamics and this equation appears there. Thanks!

Comment: There is no closed form solution, that's the problem.